# How to find cached objects from java heap dump

Tags: java, caching, memory-management, heap-memory

I am looking for instructions for finding cached objects from the heap dump created by jmap. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cached" is a bit unclear in this context. But I assume you have a memory leak to chase?

Try [Eclipse's Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), it's free and gives many good ways of investigating that heap.

Comment: The VisualVM/Netbeans is also free.  YourKit is not free, but I find this the most useful. Try the free ones first.